# Text file transfer from ESP32 to mobile app

Tags: android, csv, esp32, app-inventor

I want to take a text file from an ESP32 module into my mobile app via Bluetooth. After which I want to be able to view the data in this file and convert this data to a csv file which I should be able to download and share.

I tried building the mobile app in MIT app inventor, but I couldn't transfer the text file from the ESP32 module.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google Search resulted in this [tutorial](https://www.electronicshub.org/esp32-bluetooth-tutorial/), specifically summarized with:

---

### ...setup and start Bluetooth communication and also a couple of simple projects involving data transfer between ESP32 and a smart phone over Bluetooth Communication...

- You need to configure your Bluetooth Serial connection in your `void setup()` function.
- You need to start a Bluetooth Serial connection, and loop that in your `void loop()` function.
- Your ESP32 Module is now visible to your smartphone.

If you're following the tutorial, you'll quickly realize that it requires a 3rd party app to do the communication.

The MIT App Inventor [Page](https://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/connectivity.html#BluetoothClient) regarding the `BluetoothClient` component has the function: `ReceiveText(numberOfBytes)`. It says that it:

- Reads a number of bytes from the input stream and converts them to text.
- If numberOfBytes is negative, read until a delimiter byte value is read.

Using the other methods that are available to you, you can determine whether or not the Device is connected to the ESP32.

Additional Notes:

---

- You'll need the ESP32 "address", which is obtainable with this function:

```
void printDeviceAddress() {

  const uint8_t* point = esp_bt_dev_get_address();
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    char str[3];
    sprintf(str, "%02X", (int)point[i]);
    Serial.print(str);
    if (i < 5){
      Serial.print(":");
    }
  }
}
```

This is what MIT App Inventor requires as the "address" to connect with the ESP32. [Source](https://linuxhint.com/esp32-bluetooth-address-arduino-ide/)

- You will want to loop looking for data in your app:

[image: Test Image]

### In conclusion:

I suggest that you follow the `electronicshub.org` tutorial and make sure that your ESP32 is successfully sending and receiving data. Once you've gotten that to work, the MIT App Inventor `BluetoothClient` is all you need to send/receive data.